# Why aren't Facebook using svgs for their icons?

Tags: facebook, svg, icons, png

Why are Facebook using really shitty pngs for their icons? They look like crap.

Is it because of browser compability?
Speed?
Browser performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook use a sprite sheet in png format, such as this: https://en-gb.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/yG/r/dJcoEOc7BcH.png -- a sprite sheet will be much more efficient to load (a single http request) as opposed to multiple requests (one for each image file say).

They also use SVGs as you can see here: https://en-gb.facebook.com/business/products/pages

So, Facebook are using a mix of formats - I imagine they are using "the right tool for the job" as and when they see fit.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to make a sprite sheet that is an SVG.

Comment: That's correct Paul...